# Read two column list from file and sort

Tags: python

I have a file with two columns of floats and want to sort them.
My code so far

```
import numpy as np
csv = np.genfromtxt ('test.dat')
#print csv
new = sorted(csv, key=lambda x: x[0])
print new
```

print csv yields

```
[  2.54931641e+00   9.27734375e+00]
[  2.52001953e+00   1.01318359e+01]
[  2.56884766e+00   9.76562500e+00]
[  2.57617188e+00   1.07421875e+01]
.....
```

but print new yields

```
[array([ -2.59960938, -12.57324219]), array([ -2.59960938, -12.6953125 ]), array([ -2.59960938, -12.81738281]), array([
-2.59960938, -12.81738281]), array([ -2.59960938, -14.03808594]), array([ -2.59716797, -13.91601562]), array([ -2.594726
56, -15.38085938]), array([ -2.59472656, -13.18359375]), array([ -2.59228516, -12.57324219]), array([ -2.58984375, -12.9
3945312]), array([ -2.58740234, -16.11328125]), array([ -2.58740234, -12.57324219]), array([ -2.58496094, -15.25878906])
```

This new output is not processable for me. Is there a way to make the list look like before it was sorted (but being sorted, ofc)

**Edit:**
I tested the two given solutions

```
new1 = sorted(csv.tolist(), key=lambda x: x[0])

new2 = np.sort(csv, axis=0)
```

and got contradicting results. To further test the code I made up a test file

```
1   33
2   44
4   55
3   66
3   88
5   99
-4  111
17  22
4   77
```

this gives me

```
print new1[0]
>>>[-4.0, 111.0]
print new2[0]
>>>[ -4. 22.]
```

new2 is not working properly, but why?

Comment: could you please post a sample of your file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you would like to get the a list of lists instead of a list of `array` objects, you can try passing to sorted `csv` as a list, like this:
`new = sorted(csv.tolist(), key=lambda x: x[0])`

Answer (score 1):

`sorted` is a builtin Python function that returns a list. You are looking for [`np.sort`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.sort.html).

```
new = np.sort(csv, axis=0)
```

Comment: this doesn't work right. See my edit in the question.

Comment: Whoops misread the question. Sorry. Just call 'np.array' on your original solution